# extern int main(int argc, char* argv[]) use?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, sfml

I've been reading SFML's source code. I found the way it wraps the win32 in a fashion like this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32 //something like that
#include <windows.h>
extern int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, INT)
{
   return main(__argc, __argv);
}
#endif
```

so `line 4` I see this typical win32 program entry. however what are the `extern main` and `return main(__argc, __argv)` doing?

what's `__argc` with the underscore?

as in my own main function after loading SFML, all I need is to write `int main()`.

I am very curious how this work in terms of writing cross-platform codes. (I used the same fashion in my win32 code, it worked!! anyone explain the magic behind this please???)

Comment: Please don't have line-numbers in the code-snippets you show. If you need to mark out a line or something, add a comment on that line.

Comment: As for e.g. `__argc` and `__argv` have you checked the documentation for your compiler? It should be noted that any symbol beginning with two underscores are reserved for internal use by the "implementation" (i.e. the compiler and its standard library).

Comment: As for `extern main(...);` i't s a normal function forward declaration. The `extern` keyword is usually not needed as the symbol should have external [linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage) by default.

Comment: This just means that SFML expects users of the library to provide a `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` function

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I see, thanks. I've removed the line numbers. so I just found that [__argc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/argc-argv-wargv?view=msvc-160) is a Microsoft thing. yeah extern that part I get now thanks.  and how does the WinMain and return works??

Comment: @Frank Hi, so this: [SFML-Turorial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-window.php) Users only need to put `main()`. where's the arguments gone?

Comment: The return is simple: The code calls the `main` function, and takes the value that `main` returns and returning from `WinMain`. It's equivalent to `int result; result = main(__argc, __argv); return result;` I.e. it treats `main` like any other function that can be called and return a value.

Comment: @JoonrooTaugh The unfortunate answer is that functions called `main` are special in that way. (sort of..., the real technical explanation in that case is a little weird, and has to do with how C calling conventions operate)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ahh damn. I think I got it, so the real main entry is actually on this file instead of user's  file with the main() on it. so user defined main is only a definition of this so-called main function which on window's apps should be another `WinMain`? am I correct?? (please can you add your reply to the answer if you'd like :)

Comment: @Frank I see. so the arguments are the arguments from the compilers?? or the ones I passed to executable?

Comment: @JoonrooTaugh It's more that If you declare `extern foo(int, bool);` in a **cpp** file, and implement `foo()` in another cpp file that is blind to that extern declaration, calling `foo(12, true)` from the first file will "work" because the implemented function will just ignore the registers containing the arguments. And since the compiler does not see the mismatch during compilation, it "looks" clean. For `main()`, that behavior is formally official.

Comment: @Frank thank you, that makes scene now!! :)

Comment: @JoonrooTaugh It's worth noting that SFML calling `main(argc, argv)` while expecting that some users will implement `main()` is playing a bit loose with the rules. There's an argument to be made that it's warranted in this specific case, but it's certainly not a pattern anyone should be using without a damn good reason. On the flip side, it's kind of Microsoft's fault for making `WinMain()` the entry point instead of the standard `main()`, so it's a bit of a fighting evil with evil type situation.

Comment: @Frank agree!! writing WinAPI is a pure pain. Do you have some tips or recommendations how to wrap Win32 code into a generic architecture?(for you know, a more multi-platform targeted). Books, articles answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the `extern main` and `return main(__argc, __argv)` doing?

If you are compiling on a windows platform, SFML defines the WinMain entry point for you, and calls your `main(int argc, char* argv[])` with `__argc` and `__argv` which are explained by the [relevant documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/argc-argv-wargv?view=msvc-160):

> The `__argc` global variable is a count of the number of command-line
> arguments passed to the program. `__argv` is a pointer to an array of
> single-byte-character or multi-byte-character strings that contain the
> program arguments.

SFML does this, exacly such that that developers can use the standard main function even in a Win32 Application project, and thus keep a portable code. The comments in [SFML/MainWin32.cpp](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Main/MainWin32.cpp) explain this.